# How to calculate the number of matching positions among two strings?

Tags: r, match, character

I have two vectors with characters in each cell.

```
Ex:       Vet 1.     Vet 2. 

Row 1.    AAABBC     BCABDE 

Row 2.    EDAACD     ADBBEE

...         ...        ...

Row n.    CCCDAC     EECEAC
```

Comparing the characters in same row, e.g., AA**AB**BC and BC**AB**DE, we have two matches in the same position (A - 3rd position - and B - 4th position).
I want to create a third vector (Vet 3) containing the number of matches between Vet 1 and Vet 2 for characters in the same row.

Output

```
         Vet. 3

Row 1.     2

Row 2.     1

...      ...

Row n.     3
```

I don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

We can split every character in both the columns and count how many of them match. In case, number of characters are not the same in both the columns we can use the one only minimum number of characters to compare.

Assuming `df` is your dataframe name and `col1`, `col2` are column names.

```
mapply(function(x, y) {
   len <- min(length(x), length(y))
   sum(x[1:len] == y[1:len])
}, strsplit(df$col1, ''), strsplit(df$col2, ''))

#[1] 2 1 3
```

---

If we are guaranteed to have same number of characters in both the columns we can simplify this :

```
mapply(function(x, y) sum(x == y), strsplit(df$col1, ''), strsplit(df$col2, ''))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c("AAABBC", "EDAACD", "CCCDAC"), col2 = c("BCABDE", 
"ADBBEE", "EECEAC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```